# My iPhone 6s Plus doesn't want to download apps. Whenever I touch get it says that my request cannot be processed

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

[image]

My iPhone 6s Plus doesn't want to download apps. Whenever I tap on <kbd>GET</kbd> as per the above screenshot, I get an error stating:

> Your request cannot be processed. Error code: 1009.

Answer (score 2):

Error 1009 appears when Apple sees the phone's IP address as coming from a location or country where the Apple Store (or this particular app) is blocked. Your phone's screenshot shows connectivity through Cubacel, so I presume you're in Cuba...and I'll bet Apple blocks the download for that reason. You could consider using a VPN (virtual private network) to anonymize your location, which might allow the download...and which might also contravene Cuban law.